# How to solve a differential equation with a term to a power?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How would I solve an equation where one of the differential terms is to a power? For example:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+k(\frac{dy}{dx})^2=0$$

I've been given advice to use the $D$ operator which apparently means $\frac{d}{dx}()$ but I'm not sure how that's applicable to this scenario. Any alternative suggestions or explanations would be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you only have second and first derivatives of $y$ and no 
un-differentiated $y$, you could try to introduce the new function $v=\frac{dy}{dx}$. Your differential equation will turn into $\frac{dv}{dx}+kv^2=0$, and I guess you will manage to take it from here.

Comment: So for the substitution, could you use the chain rule? I'm fairly new to differential equations so sorry if the question sounds stupid.

Comment: No need for chain rule here. For the substitution, I gave all details. You now need to solve the new differential equation for $v$. Then use the result to solve for $y$.

Comment: how would I go about solving such a differential equation?

Comment: It is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).